# Elasticsearch with postman - no handler found for uri

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I'm working on a scraping project and I want to store my data in an elasticsearch database. My connection between my scraper and elasticsearch seems to be ok because I have some data.

I installed elasticsearch through a docker image like this :

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1
```

It's the first time that I use elasticsearch so i want to play a bit with it so i decided to use Postman. When I'm trying to get an ES item through postman I get this error :

```
{"error": "no handler found for uri [http://localhost:9200/scrapy-wouahome/_doc/nJQ55nkBYs4cp5KYjzfQ] and method [GET]"}
```

I configured the proxy params like this : [proxy params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvyjl.png)

This this my request to get an item by id : [get an item with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lExTZ.png)

I also tried to get my item through the curl method and it's working : [get an item with curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN7rh.png)

And I tried to access to my item directly through my browser and it's also working: [get an item with my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpeVT.png)

So it seems I can access to my elasticsearch database but I guess I missed something in my postman's configuration. I'm a beginner with postman and elasticsearch so I would appreciate your help.

Of course I did some research about this error but I didn't find anything relevant..

Answer (score 0):

Finally i just turn off the ssl certificate and proxy and it's works !!